# Django Aggregate ManyToMany fields

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

Say I have Django models like so:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

What's the best way to get the the number of books each author created (preferably ordered) within a query or two?

The Author set might get pretty big, so I'm looking for a way to avoid iterating over all of it.

Answer (score -4):

in your model book add...

```
...
author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
...
```

and to get then you use a QuerySet like

```
...
Author.objects.get(id=some_id).book_set.all() # this line, return all book of these author, if you want get the number just add at end '.count()'
...
```

Comment: You're not answering the question--you're changing his model.

Comment: is the same... you can do it the same with your relation model, the important is `...book_set.all()`

Comment: That's true, but actually I was hoping there's a way to do this in a query (or two) instead of iterating over all options, as the Author set might get pretty big. I'll clarify my question. Thanks!

Comment: if you want get it in a Author's QuerySet, you must use, `Author.objects.filter(some_field=some_value).aggregate(num_books=models.Sum('book'))`, then each author has an attribute 'num_books', or directly you can filter by 'num_books'